# PHP errors - Notice: Undefined index in shorthand if/else

Tags: php

I know `Notice: Undefined index` error is about lack of `isset()`.

Below statements doesn't get any errors or notices :

```
if (isset($_SESSION['userid'])) {
    $userid = $_SESSION['userid'];  
}
```

But following statements, get `Notice: Undefined index` :

```
$userid = $_SESSION['userid'] ? isset($_SESSION['userid']) : NULL;
```

Please tell me why when using shorthand `if/else` it get notice?

Comment: Because one have to learn the right shorthand syntax beforehand?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are doing it wrong. It should be something like:

```
$userid = isset($_SESSION['userid']) ? $_SESSION['userid'] : NULL;
```

First check if the variable is set then use its value.

Answer (score 2):

try putting it the right way round

```
$userid = isset($_SESSION['userid']) ? $_SESSION['userid']  : NULL;
```